# Convert a Linq result to a datatable

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am trying to convert a Linq result in to a datatable

I have a linq that is created from a dataset of many tables.  It returns results, but I need to get the results in to a new datatable.

Examples I have seen say I sould be able to use .CopyToDataTable But for some reason this doesn't work?

I have noticed that I can to .ToArray perhaps I can then turn the array in to a datatable?  Seems line an unnecessary step?

Here is my query: (it works)

```
 Dim R2 = From Inq In DS.Tables!CNLocalInquiry.AsEnumerable()
             Join Cust In DS.Tables!CustomerID.AsEnumerable() On Inq.Field(Of Integer)("CNLocalInquiry_Id") Equals Cust.Field(Of Integer)("CNLocalInquiry_Id")
                Select New With {.date = Inq.Field(Of String)("date"),
                                .CName = Cust.Field(Of String)("CustomerNumber"),
                                .Name = Cust.Field(Of String)("name")}

Dim MemberInq as new datatable 
MemberInq = R2.CopyToDataTable() <-- this doesn't work
```

This is what my query returns:
[image: query returns]

Comment: The method you are trying to use expects `T` to be of type `DataRow`.

Comment: btw, your join is being done in memory instead of in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(this is the easy to code way... this will not be performant for large datasets)

```
public static class ToolsEx
{
    public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        var t = typeof(T);
        var dt = new DataTable(t.Name);
        var props = t.GetProperties()
                     .Select(p => new { N = p.Name, Getter = p.GetGetMethod() })
                     .Where(p => p.Getter != null)
                     .ToList();
        props.ForEach(p => dt.Columns.Add(p.N));

        foreach (var item in items)
            dt.Rows.Add(props.Select(p => p.Getter.Invoke(item, null)).ToArray());

        return dt;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've saved this as an extension method and it's always worked perfectly:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx

Examples here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921.aspx

Hope that does the trick!